# ElasticSearch & Tire. Search for an object with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, nested-attributes, tire

I've spent several hours trying to solve the problem. I hope someone can help me.

First, here's some code to illustrate the structure:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  attr_accessible :name, :website, :addresses_attributes

  has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, allow_destroy: true

  after_touch() { tire.update_index }

  include_root_in_json = false

  mapping do
    indexes :name, boost: 10
    indexes :addresses do
      indexes :street
    end
  end

  def self.search(params)
    s = tire.search(load: true) do

    query do
      boolean do
        must { string params[:query] } if params[:query]
        must { term "addresses.street", params[:location] } if params[:location]
      end
    end

    s.results
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    to_json( include: { addresses: { only: [:street] } } )
  end
end


class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Attributes
  attr_accessible :street

  # Associations
  belongs_to :company, touch: true
end
```

When I'm trying to search for company with particular street name (calling `Company.search({location: 'example_street_name', query: 'example_name'})` I get no results.

Indexing looks fine for me. That's one of the requests:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/companies/company/1351" -d '{
  "created_at": "2012-12-29T13:41:17Z",
  "name": "test name",
  "updated_at": "2012-12-29T13:41:17Z",
  "website": "text.website.com",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "street": "test street name"
    }
  ]
}'
```

I've tried many things to get the results. Nothing worked. It seems I must have missed something basic.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a `term` query for the "addresses.street" field, which is not analyzed, so you must pass in lowercased etc. values.

Try using the `match` query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it does not change anything. I've tried many things. Went through the API. I've tried filters also. Nothing worked. What I try to achieve is `Company.includes(:addresses).where(addresses: {street: params[:location]})`